# Safely reinitialising member objects

Tags: c#, oop, interface, architecture, camera

Hoping this is an appropriate question because I understand it could be quite general or even very subjective.

I am currently refactoring a camera class. I'm going to be reusing the overall camera within a service class once I have it finished but I'm running into a few problems.

The camera class itself is meant to be an object oriented wrapper around a camera API provided by a manufacturer (so that several camera implementations can be used interchangeably). From this point on I'm going to call the manufacturers camera object "CAM".

I'm planning this for the current design:

- ICamera: Contains the methods and properties for acquisition of images as well as connect()/disconnect() methods and connected/disconnected events.
- ISerialCamera: An extension of camera with the addition of a serial port object.
- ISerialPort: Contains methods for reading/writing serial.

Both the ICamera and ISerialPort implementations depend CAM. Also, when a connection is made a new instance of CAM is created. This is where my problem comes in:

- Instantiate an ICamera.
- Camera.Connect();
- An error occurs notifying
- ICamera that is has disconnected.
- I connect the camera again (generating a new instance of CAM internally).

Is it bad practice for me to now reinstantiate the serial port object with the new instance of CAM? I ask because it seems like an illogical move for an object oriented design.

For instance, someone may take my serial camera object and decide to use the ISerialPort as an argument to some function (for example).

If I was to reinstantiate my serial port object, then their local reference to the serial port is now invalid and the client of the serial will have more difficulty sorting out the issue of a disconnect.

Although some might see this as acceptable, I would rather make usage of my camera objects as intuitive and easy as possible. In my ideal solution the ISerialPort reference will *always* point to the same instance, but the serial port would be associated with the new CAM instance.

I'd though of the following solutions:

1. As a serial port implementation is specific to the camera implementation, I could have added an additional method to the implementation but *not* the interface, e.g. ISerialPort.Reinitialise(CAM), and then the ICamera implementation would be able to cast it's serial port to the implementation type (CAMSerialPort), giving it the ability to call the new Reinitialise() method.
2. Remove the serial port object completely. ISerialCamera extends ICamera, but ISerialCamera directly contains the methods for reading/writing serial without the addition of a serial port object. This works but I would rather go for a composition-over-inheritance solution. I'd like to keep away from inheritance hierarchies if possible and I feel it almost pushes me towards breaking things like the single reponsibility principles by just bolting on more features directly to a single object.

These would solve the issue, but I'm not sure if it would be considered ad practice, I don't like the idea of internal casting just to get access to a method (but maybe I'm just prejudiced).

Some helpful hints towards any specific patterns that solve this problem or any changes/additions to my design choice would be greatly appreciated.

Just to finally make clear, I need the interfaces that will be used by the client to be as general as possible, absolutely nothing declared that is specific to a type of camera implementation and it's internal (or lack of) API.

*EDIT:* some additional information to make it clearer.

- The acquisition of images doesn't require the serial port (which is why I chose an ICamera that isn't serial enabled).
- The serial port is a feature of certain cameras to allow serial comms
- In my use case, the camera is part of a larger hardware solution that contains a microprocessor. The serial port is there so I can use the camera to send read/write serial to the micro firmware (rather than actually operate on the camera).

The serial port acts as a link between my client computer and the firmware running on a separate board.

Also, the CAM API may not provide disconnect notifications, so the whole thing needs to be synchronised based on failure. I have a serial monitor that periodically polls the device status.

- When the device is in certain states, I want to disable acquisition.
- When a serial read fails, I can assume the camera was disconnected.
- When device status is enabled but an acquisition happens before a read occurs (or a read occurs during an acquisition) I need to handle a disconnection and an abort of the acquisition.

Summation of use cases:

- Acquire an image (if enabled and connected)
- Read/write serial to firmware (if camera connected)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really hard to answer without some specific examples of code and examples of issues, but from the bit I've been able to gather here are some possible architectural alternatives that I might use.

First of all - as I think you're intuiting - you likely do not want the camera exposing an `ISerialPort` interface.

---

You can have `ICamera` indicate an abstraction for a camera and you always require the user to indicate which port to send signals to

```
camera.TakePhoto(serialPort);
```

---

You can force `ICamera` to require connection with a serial port

```
camera.TakePhoto(); //throw  InvalidOperationException
camera.Connect(serialPort);
camera.TakePhoto(); //Ok
```

---

My preference would be for the serial port act as a factory for your camera

```
var camera = serialPort.Connect();
```

you can even then have the camera be an `IDisposable` - this makes better intuitive sense if you instead renamed the interface to `ICameraConnection`

```
using(ICameraConnection camera = cameraPort.Connect()) {
    camera.TakePhoto();
}
```

---

How that helps a bit.

Comment: I like the idea of having a CameraConnection type but I'm still having trouble with coordination. There are some details I left out:
 - The camera itself is used purely for acquisition. But the physical camera has the ability for serial communication. Serial comms requires the camera. The acquisition doesn't require serial comms.
 - The camera will be used in several places (not simultaneously) for very different operations, e.g. taking images to calibrate an image correction routine.
 - The serial purpose is read/writes to non-cam firmware, the camera provides the serial port for the link.